# Acceder a un recurso de Audio desde la carpeta Resource de mi proyecto En Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#

Estoy trabajando en un juego en C#, necesito que cuando se ejecute la aplicación y cuando oprima alguna tecla del formulario se reproduzcan audios, los audios quiero que estén en los recursos de mi proyecto.

Y quiero acceder a ellos desde un método, No quiero poner rutas de acceso locales de mi pc porque en caso de que exporte mi proyecto se perderá la ruta de mis audios siempre y no funcionaran, por ahora tengo este metodo:

```
 private void tecla()
 {
       SoundPlayer sonido;
       sonido = new SoundPlayer(Application.StartupPath + "tecla.wav");
       sonido.Play();
 }
```

Pero no me funciona, agradeceria su ayuda Gracias.

Comment: no son url.. son rutas a tu disco local. Y mas alla de tu problema, podrias mandar los audios con tu programa (al instalarlo) y buscarlos ahi... que es lo que estas haciendo con ese codigo...

Comment: El problema esque con ese codigo que esta hay no funciona, necesito el codigo correcto las sentencias que funcionan

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: El archivo existe en esa ruta? estas haciendo que copie los archivos de tu proyecto al compilar?

Comment: Claro el archivo se encuentra en esta ruta C:\Users\User\source\repos\juegodelahorcadoencsharp\bin\Debug, el problema es que comprobé que el método si accede hasta esa ruta pero no detecta el archivo de audio tecla.wav, y no se como es la instrucción especifica en el método para que lo detecte

Comment: @NicolasGomezZ, si tiene dicho sonido agregado a `Resources`, este objeto es un `Stream` puede hacerlo de esta manera: `System.IO.Stream str = Properties.Resources.tecla;
System.Media.SoundPlayer snd = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(str);
snd.Play();`

Comment: @J.Rodríguez Efectivamente esa era la instrucción que necesitaba, no sabía que era un objeto stream, (Soy nuevo en C#) Pero ya me funciono el archivo de audio muchas gracias por su ayuda (Y).

Comment: @NicolasGomezZ me alegra que le haya servido, yo podría colocar la respuesta debajo, si desea marcarla como que ha resuelto su problema.

Comment: Claro que sí,  si quiere coloque la respuesta y le calificó..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como ya le había mencionado en los comentarios si tiene dicho sonido agregado a `Resources`, debería tratar este objeto como un `Stream` puede hacerlo de esta manera:

```
System.IO.Stream str = Properties.Resources.tecla; ///Aqui esta el sonido wav...
System.Media.SoundPlayer sonido = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(str); 
sonido.Play();
```

Que de igual manera también puede ser:

```
 System.Media.SoundPlayer sonido = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
 sonido.Stream = Properties.Resources.tecla;
 sonido.Play();
```

Fuente: [Documentación Clase SoundPlayer (MSDN)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/api/system.media.soundplayer?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)